# JTable does not show Object [][] data

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file-io, jtable

I need to some help about JTable.I'm trying to read data from "Contact.txt" file and populate my table with that datas.I can get data from file correctly with adding to Object[][] 2D array without any problem.When I try to add this Object array to table not happens any thing.
Sorry for my bad English.

Contacts.txt file include "Name","LastName","Phone Num","Email" s.

And this Class read the text and add it to Object :

```
public class ReadFromText {

public boolean ReadTable(Object [][] data) {

    boolean status = false;

    File file = new File("/Users/MacbookPro/Documents/Contacts.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bf = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String textLine = null;
        String [] text = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                while ((textLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    text = textLine.split("    ");
                    data[i][j] = text[j];
                    status = true;
                    System.out.println(data[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        bf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

This part of code from **main Class** :

```
Object [][]datas = new Object[10][4];

ReadFromText r = new ReadFromText(); //new object from ReadData class
    if(r.ReadTable(datas)== true){ 
        System.out.println("OK");//just for to be sure
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
    model = new DefaultTableModel(datas, columNames);
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    table.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
    table.setRowHeight(25);
    table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

It' return "OK" check it from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWEtF.png)

But JTable is empty !!! : look it from [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1O92.png)

I hope to anyone can help me.***THANKS FOR ALL***

Comment: What do you get when you print out  datas ?

Comment: @c0der Thanks for replay but I tried it ..U can see the result from second picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to read the data from the file is wrong. Think about it for a minute. You start the outer loop with a value of 0, then you have you inner loop with a value of 0 and then you read the entire file using the while loop.

You want your logic to read a single line of data, split that line and add then add the data to the array. So the logic should be something like:

```
int row = 0;

while ((String textLine = bf.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String text = textLine.split("    ");

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
         data[row][i] = text[i];
    }

    row++
}
```

However, you should NOT be using Arrays to hold the data. You should never hardcode the size of a data structure since it does not allow you to add new data. Instead you should be using a Vector to read the data. Then it doesn't matter is you have 10 rows of data or 100.

Using this approach the code would be something like:

```
Vector data = new Vector();

while ((String textLine = bf.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String text = textLine.split("    ");
    Vector row = new Vector();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
         row.addElement( text[i] );
    }
}
```

So you would need to change the method to return the Vector of data. You would also need to change your "columnNames" to be added to a Vector so you can create the TableModel using the two Vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it working but it just filling  first columns .Now I'm trying to split it with correct way.

Comment: @CoderACJHP, `Now it working but it just filling first columns` - the column index in the data array was never changing in my "untested" code. See edit for one way to change the column. This is another reason to use the Vectors since you don't have to worry about indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer will help you find the problem. It is also meant to demonstrate the importance of posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like the following:

mport java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

```
public class TestTable extends JFrame  {

    public TestTable() {

        super("Main");
        setSize(400, 300);

        Object [][]datas = new Object[][]{
            {"A1", "A2","A3","A4"},
            {"B1", "B2","B3","B4"}
        };

        Object[] columNames = {"Name","LastName","Phone Num","Email"};
        DefaultTableModel    model = new DefaultTableModel(datas, columNames );
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

        add(new JScrollPane(table));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }
}
```

Not only an MCVE helps you get better and faster response, in many cases, like this one, it helps you pin point the problem and **solve it by yourself**.
Removing everything that is not essential to reproduce the problem, help you (and who ever tries to help) focus on where the problem is. 
In this case you can see that eliminating the input part, you can see that the `JTable` works fine. 

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replay.My problem in populate  2d array, when tried to move while((text = bf.readLine()) !=){} out of 2 for loops I get result like this :[Ljava.lang.String;@3ede05c0

Comment: I know the problem is there. That is why I posted the comment "What do you get when you print out datas ?"

Comment: I getting right data all thing is OK but the table still empty. After that we solved half of the problem with Mr.@camickr :) Now only first columns filling and need to solve this.Maybe need to use split with different regex?? Do you have any idea about this? "just filling first columns"  THANX

Comment: "I getting right data" - I doubt it. 1. print it out before it is used by the model. You may be surprised. 2.If the data is 100% checked post another question with an [MCVE]